# Xamarin/SQLite/C# - How to delete a row from listview and SQLite table with menu item delete

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, listview, xamarin

**Problem:** So this is not an uncommon question on coding forums but there seems to be a variety of ways in which people apply delete buttons and after days of attempts I'm asking for some advice regarding my method.

I have a simple app that takes some user input and uses it to to calculate holiday leave days. I have a simple SQLite db set up like so to handle new entries:

```
public class LeaveEntry
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Hours { get; set; }
    public string Days { get; set; }
}
```

I then set up the DB connection in this class and create some save and delete methods:

```
public class Database
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

    public Database (string dbPath)
    {
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<LeaveEntry>().Wait();
    }

    public Task<List<LeaveEntry>> GetLeaveEntryAsync()
    {
        return _database.Table<LeaveEntry>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveLeaveEntry(LeaveEntry leaveEntry)
    {
        return _database.InsertAsync(leaveEntry);
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteLeaveEntry(LeaveEntry leaveEntry)
    {
        return _database.DeleteAsync(leaveEntry);
    }
}
```

Using the SaveLeaveEntry method I can successfuly add leave entries to a listview on another page but I'm having trouble deleting them. On this listview page I have added a menu item with a delete button when the user holds the listview item. When they select the delete menu item, I currently have it set to do this:

```
public void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LeaveEntry itemToDelete = ((sender as MenuItem).BindingContext as LeaveEntry);

        // Unfinished code attempt
        await App.Database.DeleteLeaveEntry(new LeaveEntry
        {
            ID = listView.SelectedItem.
        });
    }
```

In my mind, I am trying to use the selected item reference to pull that item from the db but it is simply doing nothing. I know I am missing something simple here but am getting a little burned out on the issue. Any help is appreciated. Can provide further code or info if required.

Comment: Your `listView.Selected` item is the whole `LeaveEntry` object? In that case you can just `await App.Database.DeleteLeaveEntry((LeaveEntry)listView.SelectedItem);`

Comment: why not just do `App.Database.DeleteLeaveEntry(itemToDelete)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my mind, I am trying to use the selected item reference to pull
> that item from the db but it is simply doing nothing.

You should use the current holded item as the parameter of method `DeleteLeaveEntry` instead of creating a new item.

Please try the following code:

```
 LeaveEntry itemToDelete = ((sender as MenuItem).BindingContext as LeaveEntry);
 App.Database.DeleteLeaveEntry(itemToDelete);
```

**Note:**

In addition,if you don't trigger event `ItemSelected` of your `listview`,the value of `listView.SelectedItem` will be `null`.

Comment: Okay, that's done it. I realise that the listview item is being deleted but not updating until I move away from the page and come back so I think I just need to add a refresh method or maybe trigger the OnAppearing method again. Thanks so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

### Basic Delete Method

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.databaseLocation))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<DATA>();
                var list = conn.Table<DATA>().Where(x => x.text == "asd").ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                   conn.Delete(list[i]);
                }
            }
```